# Any way of getting Kinect V2 tracking data with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, kinect, openkinect

My question is: How to get Kinect for Windows V2 tracking data to Javascript for HTML5 games or other browser hacks.

I used the Zigfu browser plugin with my old Kinect to work with Javascript in the browser and that worked on my Macintosh too. I also know that Microsoft has released the kinect.js v1.8 for web development. There is also the node package called pgte/node-openni (find on GIT) that enables you to get Kinect data using web sockets. **Problem is that NONE of these work with the new sensor.**

The reason why I believe that this is possible is because I found these projects and they seem to work fine with Javascript and the new sensor but I can't extract enough information from these articles to start off development:

Project 1:
http://blog.derivatived.com/posts/Kinect-version-2-Operated-Robot-Hand/

Project 2:
http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2014/08/19/kinect-for-windows-v2-sdk-hello-skeletal-world-for-the-3d-javascript-windows-8-1-app-developer.aspx

Comment: Any news on this? :(

Comment: For now, for my project, we did it the other way round - embed the web page in an app based on a Kinect v2 example app. I'll give the details later as a proper answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A node module has been published and that now fully works with the Kinect V2:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/kinect2

According to the author once the official SDK is installed on a Windows PC the example from the repository readme can simply run the in node. Once the skeleton data is accessible in node you can publish it through a websocket (socket.io) and read it from the browser on the host machine or another one.

Comment: "according to the author", "Version 0.0.3 last updated 19 days ago" - can anyone confirm this actually works?

Comment: It's probably not for commercial use but   tested it and it definitely works! Good for a few hacks and personal projects.

The official SDK is out now so let's hope the author updates this.

Comment: Also confirming it works with kinectv2. Still looking for documentation on the exact meaning of the bodyFrame attributes.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2014/08/18/kinect-for-windowsv2-sdk-hello-skeletal-world-for-the-javascript-windows-8-1-app-developer.aspx) you can't run the app in web browser , but you can build win 8.1 store apps with all features supported , to do so you have to install :

1. [Kinect v2 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44561)
2. [Latest MS visual studio available.](http://www.visualstudio.com/)

and voila , you are good to go , also i would suggest all videos posted [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Programming-Kinect-for-Windows-v2)

Comment: Props for the video links!